# How to add seeded data into the mongodb using docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a mongo-seed image and mongo image set up 
[image: Docker Images]
How can i run the mongo database up with the seeded data in docker.

Answer (score -1):

use docker link in-order to link 2 dependent containers

It explained here , it might helpfull

https://rominirani.com/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-linking-containers-69a4e5bf50fb

If your using docker-compose then here is the solution which you looking

https://gist.github.com/jschwarty/6f9907e2871d1ece5bde53d259c18d5f